# How to install Nginx on OpenShift

Tags: nginx, openshift

Though I followed https://blog.openshift.com/lightweight-http-serving-using-nginx-on-openshift/ step by step, I ended up getting the error 503, telling me service is unavailable. There are questions on various websites, including stackoverflow, but all of them are about issues *after* a successful installation of nginx, a point I haven't arrived at yet.

I don't want to use already available cartridges - in part because most of them are out-of-date. Also, an answer to my question might be of interest to some people, inasmuch as it will teach how to run always the latest nginx server on OpenShift.

This is `rhc tail` result

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
==> app-root/logs/diy.log <==
[2014-12-06 16:55:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
[2014-12-06 16:55:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-12-06 16:55:50] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-12-06 16:55:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=255959 port=8080
127.xx.x.xxx - - [06/Dec/2014:17:11:57 EST] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
127.xx.x.xxx - - [06/Dec/2014:17:11:57 EST] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
[2014-12-06 17:32:02] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2014-12-06 17:32:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.

==> app-root/logs/server.log <==
nginx: [emerg] invalid port in ":" of the "listen" directive in /var/lib/openshi
ft/xxx/app-root/data//conf/nginx.conf:36
```

Comment: Is this cartridge on github somewhere that we can look at it?  Looks like the code that determines the port it should listen on is incorrect

Comment: I actually followed this guide (https://blog.openshift.com/lightweight-http-serving-using-nginx-on-openshift/) so I don't think it is available on github.

Comment: Or, did I understand your comment wrong?

Comment: Can you post your nginx.conf file here? or at least that section of it, there are nginx cartridges floating around on github.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! 
this is `nginx.conf`
`server {
        listen       :;
        server_name  localhost;`

and this is `nginx.conf.template`
`server {
        listen       $OPENSHIFT_IP:$OPENSHIFT_PORT;
        server_name  localhost;`

Comment: This guide (2012 year) uses environment variables:
$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP:$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT

Now it was renamed to:
$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP: $OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT

Comment: It worked - cheers! Can you post your comment as answer so that I can tick it to show that my question has been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide (2012 year) uses environment variables:  $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP:$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT

Now it was renamed to:
$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT

Comment: Yes that is true, still now using second one.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is nginx on OpenShift I would use this cartridge instead

https://github.com/gsterjov/openshift-nginx-cartridge

Comment: Cheers but I want install the latest version of Nginx - not 1.4.4.

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea how to do that!

Comment: Hi @TheSteve0, I found this: https://github.com/MadPitman/openshift-nginx-cartridge/commit/3311aeaac8ea612ef58efac81321d7428cabde0a yet it does not tell exactly how to update the bin folder.

Comment: Sorry - I think you need to read more about cartridge building or contact the owner of the github repo

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-nginx) a cartridge that's updated to the most recent nginx 1.9.12