# How to setup Nginx on OpenShift?

Tags: nginx, openshift

I have created a DIY cartridge because I need to run an app that runs on PHP 5.6 I have followed the instructions from this link: [How to install Nginx on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337280/how-to-install-nginx-on-openshift)

However, I receive this error: "Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at myapp.rhcloud.com Port 80"

I think the error might be linked to the .openshift/action_hooks/start script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# The logic to start up your application should be put in this
# script. The application will work only if it binds to
# $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:8080
#nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/testrubyserver.rb $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy |& /usr/bin/logshifter -tag diy &
# replace the $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP and $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT before starting up the server
sed -e "s/`echo '$OPENSHIFT_IP:$OPENSHIFT_PORT'`/`echo $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT`/" $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/conf/nginx.conf.template > $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/conf/nginx.conf
nohup $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/sbin/nginx > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/server.log 2>&1 &
```

When I run rhc tail -a myapp

```
Unable to connect to the server (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name
resolution (https://openshift.redhat.com:443)). Check that you have correctly
specified your OpenShift server 'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api'.
```

What could be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift Online https://status.openshift.com facing outage. It is not today, I faced it another 2 days in recent times.

[image]

I deployed to test with [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-nginx).

```
curl -I http://myapp-abhishekghosh.rhcloud.com  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2017 20:06:16 GMT
Server: nginx/1.11.1
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 41217
Last-Modified: Sun, 23 Apr 2017 19:49:40 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "58fd0554-a101"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

You can see naked 404 page of Nginx -- http://myapp-abhishekghosh.rhcloud.com/broker/rest/api

I can not clone because authentication service is failing.

Lately I found IBM Bluemix to be more friendly with some stuffs as OpenShift lacks official support for them. You can look at their one app, they have Nginx config which appears sane to me -- https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/lets-chat-bluemix/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf . I really have least experience with IBM Bluemix at this moment.

Secondly Aruba cloud has 1 Euro per month (plus VAT) 1 GB VMWare server.

All of us gave huge effort once behind Heroku PaaS. Do we need to give so much meaningless effort behind their systems? May be depends on person.

Comment: I recieved: "Service Temporarily Unavailable" from http://myapp.rhcloud.com/broker/rest/api